# Problem with object oriented comparisons when threading in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

im not too bad at python, and ive tried to make a threaded socket client, but ive hit a problem in my code that i cant solve. Here is the code:

```
import socket
import threading
class ThreadedServer(object):
    def __init__(self, host, port, num):
        self.num = num
        self.host = host
        self.port = port
        self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        self.sock.bind((self.host, self.port))

    def listen(self):
        self.sock.listen(1)
        while True:
            client, address = self.sock.accept()
            client.settimeout(600)
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient,args = (client,address)).start()

    def listenToClient(self, client, address):
        size = 1024
        # fix this, please
        if self.num == 1:
            print("Client 1 connected")

        if self.num == 2:
            print("Client 2 connected")

        if self.num == 3:
            print("Client 3 connected")
        while True:
                data = client.recv(size)
                data = data.decode("utf-8")
                print("Client", self.num, ": ", data)                


                #   Reply 
                if data == "lad":
                    response = "nice"
                else:
                    response = data



                client.send(response.encode('utf-8'))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        host = input("Host? ")
        port_num = input("Port? ")
        try:
            port_num = int(port_num)
            print("Please connect client")            
            break
        except ValueError:
            pass

    ThreadedServer(host,port_num, 1).listen()
    ThreadedServer(host,port_num, 2).listen()
    ThreadedServer(host,port_num, 3).listen()

    ThreadedServer.listenToClient()
```

You see, when i run this, i also connect it to a rather simple client, which sends me data.
In this code, the data i receive is amply called 'data'.
The problem i have in this code is that in the section where i repeat 'if self.num:', i plan for it to give me the following code when i connect 3 client:

```
Client 1 connected
Client 2 connected
Client 3 connected
```

but instead it simply repeats 'Client 1 connected' 3 times.

It would be great if anyone could try to solve this problem for me, thanks in advance

Ps: If anyone would like the client too, just ask for it, and i will edit this post to add it in.

Comment: How does this line `ThreadedServer.listenToClient()` not throw an error? Please provide the client aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get correct output according to the code you run. Your code has two problems. The first problem is in the `main suite`. Look at the line `ThreadedServer(host,port_num, 1).listen()`. It says: create object of class `ThreadServer` and call method `listen()` which runs forever (listens to connections forever). You will never start 2 more servers `ThreadedServer(host,port_num, 2).listen()` and `ThreadedServer(host,port_num, 3).listen()`. This is good but should be fixed. So you have 1 server which can accept multiple connections. But you count servers instead of clients (this is the second problem which gives you the output you do not expect).

The solution is the following.

Run only 1 server (1 object of class `ThreadedServer`).

Add counter to the method `listen()`:

```
def listen(self):
    counter = 0
    self.sock.listen(1)
    while True:
        client, address = self.sock.accept()
        client.settimeout(600)
        counter += 1
        threading.Thread(
            target=self.listenToClient,
            args=(client, address, counter)).start()
```

Change method `listenToClient()` a little bit:

```
def listenToClient(self, client, address, client_id):
    size = 1024
    print("Client {} connected".format(client_id))
    while True:
            data = client.recv(size)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            print("Client", self.num, ": ", data)
            #   Reply
            if data == "lad":
                response = "nice"
            else:
                response = data
            client.send(response.encode('utf-8'))
```

And you will get output:

```
Client 1 connected
Client 2 connected
Client 3 connected
```

Comment: Thanks, this fixes it perfectly